# How to Edit values in Inline using Jquery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

I have created a Jquery data table.With 4 colums and using a `checkbox` when I click on that `checkbox` the values should be edited.

"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, o) {
                 $('td:eq(4) #someCheckbox', nRow).on('click', function (e) {

```
                 $('#btnedit').on('click', function () {
                     //$('#operationsdiv').show();
                     $('#show').show();
                     var selected_id = $('#someCheckbox', nRow).val();
                     // $('#hdnid').val(selected_id);
                     //  var table_data = $('#example').dataTable();
                     $('#txtempname').val(o.txtbox_name);
                     $('#txtbox_dept').val(o.txtbox_dept);
                     $('#txtbox_year').val(o.txtbox_year);
                     $('#txtbox_per').val(o.txtbox_per);
                 });
             });
         }
```

Comment: What did you try? We are not supposed to develop stuff for you, but to help you with your own code.

Comment: There is an extension called 'Editor'. Maybe that is suitable for you?
https://editor.datatables.net/

Comment: avoid thanks, please etc.. show what have you tried so far